# How can I pass a parameter to my Controller from my View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm quite new to MVC styled pages, but slowly learning. I want to be able to click an actionlink which will then pass a parameter to my controller which will use it to get something from the database, but I've tried a number of different things and the controller is only ever given null as the parameter.

In my view, I've constructed my action link as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "GetMeeting", "ChooseMeeting", null, new {meetingid = Model.MeetingId})
```

And in my Controller that deals with this request is the following:

```
public ActionResult GetMeeting(string meetingid)
    {
        var races = RaceRepository.GetRacesInMeeting(new Meeting() {MeetingId = new Guid(meetingid)});
        return View(races);
    }
```

The meetingID is always null, can someone please help me with this and let me know how to give it the parameter I want. Also, I've checked and in the view, Model.MeetingID is populated with the ID it should be.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks
Ryan

Comment: Generally speaking, the controller never directy contacts the view, it passes information back via models.

Comment: @DanielA.White this is part of a horse racing application I'm building and races is a `List<Race>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just out of the bat, I think your null might be in the wrong place. Assuming Model.name is just text, "GetMeeting" is an action name and "ChooseMeeting" is a controller name try something like this

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "GetMeeting", "ChooseMeeting", new {meetingid = Model.MeetingId}, null)
```

And your action would be something like

```
public class ChooseMeeting : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetMeeting(int meetingid)
    {
        // ...
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: The final null there in my example is for HtmlAttributes and the new object is for route values, it looks like you had them the wrong way around.

Comment: I just re-read the question and it looks like meetingid is a string. That works too, the types vary a lot - use what suits you.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did wrong. I didn't read the overloads correctly.

Comment: It happens especially when there are many overloads, good that you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

You very likely have not defined a route that passes the meetingId as a parameter that is recognized.

You intend that your ActionLink will resolve to the following (with 3 being the value of meetingId).

```
/ChooseMeeting/GetMeeting/3
```

What is actually being routed is probably this:

```
/ChooseMeeting/GetMeeting
```

This is due to the single, default MVC route being defined something very similar to this:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Request", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
  );
```

The problem here is the parameter name being "id" by default where you have named your parameter meetingId.

There are at least 3 ways to solve this:

1. Change the name of your parameter to be `id` so that the existing route will map the parameter as desired.
2. Add a route that allows the MVC route to map the passed value to a variable named `meetingId`.
3. Pass the parameter as a querystring style argument like `/ChooseMeeting/GetMeeting/?meetingId=3`

Answer (score 0):

doh! I worked it out, the problem was, I was calling the wrong overload for ActionLink. It should have been:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "GetMeeting", "ChooseMeeting",new {meetingid = Model.MeetingId},null)
```

Sorry for the time waste.

Cheers,
Ryan